# SQL Server : how to create table with columns name as schemaname.columnname

Tags: sql, sql-server, dremel

I am trying to create the table using below codes but the column name do not show schema name.

```
Select customer as `tablename.customer`
From tablename
```

Also, I tried

```
Select customer as [tablename.customer]
From tablename
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you,
KP

Comment: Please read through "how to ask a good question" and update your post accordingly - you've done half the work.

Comment: Using select you trying create table?

Comment: what it the output? an error or something else?

Comment: do you actually mean `create table` or just return values?  Help us help you.

Comment: I assume, based on your tags, that you are working in Dremel (now Apache Drill). Is this correct?

Comment: You need to decide which DBMS you are working with. Without that detail this is an unanswerable question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption of Dremel / Drill, use a table alias on your queries, e.g.

```
Select t.customer as `tablename.customer`
From tablename t;
```